# Show table's data

Tags: php, mysqli

I use this code to show data from a selected table by the user

```
$query  = 'SELECT * FROM '.$Nom_table;

$query  = $dbh -> query($query);

$result = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<table>';

while(list ($key, $array) = each($result))
{
    foreach($array as $table)
    {
        echo $table.'';
    }
}

echo '</table>';
```

by I don't know the name of the columns to show data so what's the solution to show all data from any tables ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html Using column query, you can get list of columns for any given table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is basically do something like this:

```
while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    foreach($result as $column => $value)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo $table . "<td>" . $column . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"
    }
}
```

This should work for any table in your database. Then it's just a matter of formatting your HTML to look like what you want.

Comment: but i don't know the name of the column

Comment: I've modified my loop a little. Now it loops on every line of your resultset one at a time and it's a pretty standard way of proceeding... and you don't need to know the names of the columns since it's be contained within the $column variable.

Answer (score 1):

use `SHOW COLUMNS` like this:

```
 SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r()` to print your array result, see all the columns and then do whatever you want to do...

```
while(list ($key, $array) = each($result))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
}
```

Comment: i have tried this code but the result contains many information that i don't need

Comment: print only `$array` not `$result`